# Yii2-mongodb: How to catch mongodb insert returned mongo id

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I would like to get the mongodb insert returned id for further insert specific operation my code is this:

```
 $collection1 = $collection->insert(['username' => $this->email, 
 'password' =>sha1($this->input_password), 'full_name' => $this->full_name   
 'time_created' => '', 'time_updated' => '', 'time_last_visited' => '']);
```

when i does var_dump($collection1) function it shows me output

```
  object(MongoId)#92 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "54ba2b2c64363d640f000031" }
```

but when i try to access the id it shows me errors

i tried following options:

```
$insert_id = $collection1->primaryKey();

$insert_id = $collection1->getLastInsertID();

$id = $collection1->id;

$id = (string)$collection1['id'];

$id = $collection1['_id'];
```

but no options work. What is the right way?

Comment: Your terms are incorrect. You are not returning a "collection" from the insert but it is actually the `ObjectId` value that was last inserted from that operation. So this **is** a [MongoId](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) Object

Comment: thanks for your interest @Neil Lunn

Answer (score 0):

Well i got my answer i tried another one differently & that works.

```
            $id = (string) $collection1;
```

This returns me the string formatted mongoId.

Comment: if you look at http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-objectid.php

you can see that ObjectID class is a built in php class which has an method named "__toString"

which is a magic function that is called whenever you try to treat with an object like a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $collection->insert($data);
```